# jquery get property from DOM

Tags: jquery, dom

I need to extract fields **keysUserName** and **registrationCode** and to populate some text fields with them only if **showParameters** is 'true'.

So, Im gonna always be receiving through ajax call this set of data, and always 2 items in **keys** array.
I need exatly that item in **keys** array where property profile is **'MOBILE'**

I tried something like this `var un = data.keys[0].parameters.KeysUserName` but it wont recognize it, and Im missing "where" clause mentioned above.
How to do that?

[image]

Comment: What does this have to do with the DOM? You're getting a property from an ordinary object, not the DOM.

Comment: Looks like `KeysUserName` should be lowercase, no?